# Change inner value of recursive array

Tags: php, arrays, scope

I would like to change the value of a recursive array.

One array provides the `path` to the variable to change:

`$scopePath` represents the path to change.

For example `if $scopePath==Array("owners","products","categories")`

and $tag="price";

I would like to change `$value["owners"]["products"]["categories"]["tag"]` to `true`

```
    $u=$value;
    foreach ($scopePath as $i => $s) {
        if (!isset($u[$s]))
            $u[$s]=Array();
        $u=$u[$s];
    }
    $u[$tag]=true;
```

I know the problem is because of the line $u=$u[$s] because this changes the reference to $u, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Your code actually looks fine. What isn't working as intended?

Comment: line `$u=$u[$s];` makes that the value will change the reference of `$u`. The `$value` variable doesn't change.

Comment: [I think you're looking for this](https://eval.in/33329).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `$u` referencing `$value` or an element inside `$value`.

```
$u = &$value;
foreach($scopePath as $i => $s) {
    if (!isset($u[$s]))
        $u[$s]=Array();
    $u = &$u[$s];
}
$u["tag"] = true;
```

When `$scopePath = array("owners","products","categories")`

```
print_r($value);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [owners] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [tag] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To change your `$value` variable you must use `&` in first line:

```
$u = &$value;
```